# Automating the sending of a matplotlib chart in outlook

Tags: python, matplotlib, outlook, python-imaging-library

I have created a chart in matplotlib which I would like to send somewhat automatically.

I've converted the chart to png and then saved it as a variable as follows:

```
chart = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(chart, format='png')
chart.seek(0)
im = Image.open(chart)

def get_plot():
    return im
```

It doesn't need to be in a png format to complete the task, I just thought saving it in that format would be the best way to store it.

I have then set up auto-generated email (today is a variable that holds the day's date):

```
def Emailer(text, subject, recipient):
     outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
     mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
     mail.To = recipient
     mail.Subject = subject
     mail.HtmlBody = text
     mail.Display(True)
    
    MailSubject= "Auto test mail at "+today
    MailInput=im
    MailAdress='recipient@guyIwanttosendemailsto.com'
    
    Emailer(MailInput, MailSubject, MailAdress )
```

Unfortunately when I run the code, I get an error message saying:

```
TypeError: Objects of type 'PngImageFile' can not be converted to a COM VARIANT (but obtaining the buffer() of this object could)
```

If I didn't have the 'im' variable in the 'MailInput' the email works exactly as intended. I was wondering if any of you had some advice on how to finish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to fix the issue by saving the chart to my desktop:

```
plt.savefig('chart.png')
```

Then changing the 'MailInput' line as follows (user being another dynamic variable):

```
MailInput='<html><body><img src="C:\\Users\\'+user+'\\Desktop\\chart.png" style="width:100%"/></p></body></html>'
```